# Event Subscription does not connect with the event published

Tags: wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I have two ViewModels. In one of them I publish this event

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddUbicacionEvent>().Publish(sensorUbicado.Sensor.CodigoInterno);
```

And the in the other one I have this in the constructor

```
 _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddUbicacionEvent>().Subscribe(OnReceiveUbicacion);
```

And this method

```
 private void OnReceiveUbicacion(string obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Event Captured");
    }
```

But the Code never stops in this method

I'm Using AutoFac to inject the Event Aggergator in the constructor of the view models

```
 public IContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>().As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance();
```

Then I have this

```
 public PrincipalViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IUbicacionRepository ubicacionRepository, ComponenteEscucha componenteEscucha)
    {

        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
```

And this

```
 public GestionUbicacionesViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ):base(eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
```

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: is `_eventAggregator` the same instance in both view models?

Comment: This is one of the downsides of eventaggregator. Because it's an instance you're pub/subbing you need to pass it round somehow. Either dependency injection or resources are the usual choices unless one vm is the child of the other and you can just pass it into the constructor.

Comment: if you use `ViewModelLocator`, the event aggregator is the same usually, no need to worry there. but when do your view models get created? the subscriber has to be alive (and have subscribed) when the event is published.

Comment: I'm injecting IEventAggregator in the constructor of both VMs by AutoFac

Comment: yeah, sure, but when do you navigate to each of the view models?

Comment: From PrincipalView that have 3 buttons I push one of them and show GestionUbicacionesView but are separated windows